# How to group a list of connected pairs

Tags: c#, nodes, graph-theory, edges

I have a list of connections from X to Y as follows:-

```
public class Connection
{
    private int X { get; set; }
    private int Y { get; set; }

    public Connection(int X, int Y)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }
}


List<Connection> connectionList = new List<Connection>();

connectionList.Add(new Connection(1, 2));
connectionList.Add(new Connection(1, 3));
connectionList.Add(new Connection(1, 4));
connectionList.Add(new Connection(2, 1));
connectionList.Add(new Connection(2, 3));
connectionList.Add(new Connection(2, 4));
connectionList.Add(new Connection(3, 1));
connectionList.Add(new Connection(3, 2));
connectionList.Add(new Connection(4, 1));
connectionList.Add(new Connection(4, 2));
connectionList.Add(new Connection(5, 6));
```

I want to now know from connectionList which `groups` I have. For example here are two connected graphs which represent the data above.

[image: connected graph]

The desired output from the program would be two groups, A(1, 2, 3 4) and B(5, 6).

What is the best approach for this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Think I did something like this for a simple formula parser - ended up looking at [Directed Acyclic Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) and [Red Black Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)

Comment: No haven't tried anything yet. I don't need to know the direction, just which set of points are connected and to assign a "group id".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this;

```
var groups = new List<List<int>>();
foreach (var con in connectionList)
{
    if(!groups.Any(g => g.Contains(con.X) || g.Contains(con.Y)))
    {
        groups.Add(new List<int>() { con.X, con.Y }); //con.X is not part of any group, so we can create a new one with X and Y added, since both a are in the group       
    } 
    else 
    {
        var group = groups.First(g => g.Contains(con.X) || g.Contains(con.Y));
        if(!group.Contains(con.X)) group.Add(con.X);
        if(!group.Contains(con.Y)) group.Add(con.Y);
    }
}
```

Did this from the top of my head and didn't test it either. The purpose is simple;

- If nor X and Y exist in any group, add a new group.
- If either X or Y exists in a group, either Y or X should also be part of the group, thus add it.

Given your situation, this should give you two lists; one with (1,2,3,4) and one with (5,6).

EDIT: Click [here](http://volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=41108) to see the results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find all disconnected subgraphs in your graph. What you need to do is start from a particular node and by implementing either [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to traverse all nodes that are connected to the node you start with, and mark all these nodes ass visited. When there are no more connected nodes check if there are any nonmarket nodes. If there are any start with a particular nonmarked node and perform the same action until there are no nonmarked nodes left.
You can also check the Ktuskal algorithm [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm). This algorithm is a litle more complex as it desribes all threes in disconnected weighted graph.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works well for the data set but it won't work with a different order for example:

```
connectionList.Add(new Connection(1, 2));
connectionList.Add(new Connection(3, 4));
connectionList.Add(new Connection(1, 3));
```

There is many options to go about that but one of them is:

```
var groups = new List<List<int>>();
foreach (var con in connectionList)
{
    if(!groups.Any(g => g.Contains(con.X) || g.Contains(con.Y)))
    {
        groups.Add(new List<int>() { con.X, con.Y }); //con.X is not part of any group, so we can create a new one with X and Y added, since both a are in the group       
    } 
    else 
    {
        if(groups.Where(g => g.Contains(con.X) || g.Contains(con.Y)).Count()==1)
        {
           var group = groups.First(g => g.Contains(con.X) || g.Contains(con.Y));
           if(!group.Contains(con.X)) group.Add(con.X);
           if(!group.Contains(con.Y)) group.Add(con.Y);
        }
        if(groups.Where(g => g.Contains(con.X) || g.Contains(con.Y)).Count()>1)
        {
          List<int> groupUnion= new List<int>();
          foreach(var grp in groups.Where(g => g.Contains(con.X) || g.Contains(con.Y)).ToList())
          {
            groupUnion= groupUnion.Union(grp).ToList(); 
            groups.Remove(grp);
          }
          if(!groupUnion.Contains(con.X)) groupUnion.Add(con.X);
          if(!groupUnion.Contains(con.Y)) groupUnion.Add(con.Y);              
          groups.Add(groupUnion);
        }


    }
}
```

[here](http://volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=103843) is an example of the code running